# SyntaxError: The requested module 'fs' does not provide an export named 'existsSync'

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

When I mock the fs module

```
jest.unstable_mockModule('fs', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      readFileSync: () => {
        return CONTENT_DATA;
      },
      existsSync: () => {},
    },
  };
});
```

And I try to dynamic import the controller inside the test spec

```
const { MyController } = await import('./my.controller.js');
```

I get the error:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'fs' does not provide an export named 'existsSync'

Right on "await"

But only for this one, if I change or remove it, the code works fine. I have other dynamic imports without any errors.

Why?

Comment: Your subject refers to `existsSync`, but your mock module only defines `readFileSync`.

Comment: Even mocking existsSync I got the same error

Comment: How did you add it? The error mentions a named export specifically? Did you add it under default instead?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel to me doesn't make sense, because those dynamic imports are in the unit test, not in the actual code. In other words, why on the unit tests mocking the fs module it making failing my import? Other imports works, it just that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but adding these extra mocked function worked

```
jest.unstable_mockModule('fs', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      readFileSync: () => {
        return CONTENT_DATA;
      },
    },
    existsSync: () => {}, // Mock required.
    readFileSync: () => {}, // Mock required.
  };
});
```